# Changing the on/off state of UISwitch element in XCTest

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, uiswitch, xcuitest

I have an UISWITCH element which is from a 3rd party application.
I need to write test cases where i have to modify the state of the above switch element.

i have followed this 
[From an XCUITest how can I check the on/off state of a UISwitch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222966/from-an-xcuitest-how-can-i-check-the-on-off-state-of-a-uiswitch) 
but here i can only check the state of the Switch.

Is there any possibility where i can change the state of the UISwitch element from XCUITest.

Answer (score 2):

Just tap switches to change their state.

`app.cells["Wi-Fi"].switches.element.tap()`